# CSS3 Image rotate overlay's over my text

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm trying to get a background image to rotate when I hover over it. But at the same time I want some link text over top of the picture to NOT rotate.

I have it semi working, but when the image rotates the text get's hidden behind it. and sometimes you will hover over the link, and the image doesn't rotate. Is there a way to accomplish this?

JS Fiddle: http://bit.ly/1b9bpiJ

Dev Site: http://briggs.honeycombsites.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification to the excellent answer of Zeaklous.

To avoid the counter-rotation of the text, do not rotate the base div. Place the background in a pseudo element and rotate this.

```
div.button {
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.button:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
    background: url('http://briggs.honeycombsites.com//wp-content/themes/briggs/images/btn_contact.png');
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.button:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
div.button a {
    color: #CFCAB4;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
    width: 100%; height:80%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; margin-top:-40%;
    left:50%; margin-left:-50%;
}
div.button:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
div.button a span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCAB4;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/De5VF/2/)

In the above answer, I forgot the unprefied transform in the after

```
.button:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Also, for some reason, the design breaks in firefox and IE; the font of the span needs to be set a little bit higher:

[edited demo](http://jsfiddle.net/De5VF/3/)

Comment: Thanks vals, this works great! For some reason I had to change the div.button:after z-index to 1, and the div.button a z-index to 2. But after that it worked for me.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this working for Safari, Opera, and IE? It doesn't seem to work in those browsers for me.

Comment: Have edited my answer, now I think that it works ok ..

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you set up your code this way, but `transform` has some interesting unintentional effects at times. In your case it's affecting the z-index somehow and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it

With that being said, here's how I'd do it, which is simpler to me. It involves putting the text inside the rotating element, but rotating the text in the opposite direction at the same time in order to keep it upright

```
/* Updated HTML */
<div class="button">
    <a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span>1.800 444.1515</a>
</div>

/* CSS */
div.button {
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url('wp-content/themes/briggs/images/btn_contact.png');
}
div.button:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
div.button a {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    color: #CFCAB4;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
    width: 100%; height:80%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; margin-top:-40%;
    left:50%; margin-left:-50%;
}
div.button:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-360deg);    
}
div.button a span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCAB4;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/De5VF/1/)

Let me know if you have any questions about my method

Comment: I knew there had to be another way that I just wasn't thinking of. This worked pretty well! I just sped up the rotation a bit so the color change on the hover wasn't so gradual. Thanks so much!

Comment: You could actually change the color faster than the rotation of the circle if you want (as in separately). It'd use `transition: transform .5s, color .2s;`